# PowerShell import and sort CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, sorting

I am trying to import a CSV file and then sort by a colum. Cant seem to make it work.

```
$csvPath = 'path/to/usage_new.csv'
$usage = Get-Content -Path $csvPath | Select-Object -Skip 2 | Sort-Object "Percentage Used" | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Csv
foreach ($usage1 in $usage) {Write-Host Number $usage1.Phone used $usage1."Percentage Used"%}
```

This is just pretty basic but the Sort-Object does not work?

It imports and prints to screen OK

Any advice would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get-Content reads lines of text into strings, strings don't have properties called "Percentage Used", they only have a Length.

You need to convert from CSV *before* you do the sorting, so the incoming data has "Percentage Used" properties built from the column title:

```
Import-Csv -Path $csvPath | 
    Select-Object -Skip 2 |
    Sort-Object -Property 'Percentage Used' |
    Select-Object Phone, @{Name='Used'; Expression={"{0}%" -f $_.'Percentage Used'}}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works but only if I take out the 'Select-Object -Skip 2' and remove the top two 'blank' lines from the CSV file?

Comment: That makes sense; Import-Csv is expecting quite a strict format of input, the top line becomes the headers and if it's blank, no headers to read...

Comment: OK thanks. I cant quite figure how to output the text now using my 'foreach' statement - but I can play around with that unless you have some advice!

Comment: Well, I advise you not to :p   That's why I put the last `Select-Object` in, to try and show the output in a neat PowerShell style table. Unless it really needs to be as a string, then take the last line off and replace it with `ForEach-Object { 'Number {0} used {1}%' -f $_.Phone, $_.'Percentage Used' }` - it's not a great habit to get into using `Write-Host` for general output in PS unless you know you need it.